# Materials to complement "Interacting Electrons and Quantum Magnetism" by Assa Auerbach

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

Does anyone know of any material, such as lecture notes from a university, that can complement the sometimes brief chapters of the book "Interacting Electrons and Quantum Magnetism" by Assa Auerbach?

Any suggestions for supplemental material for this book will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

These lecture notes should be helpful for sections I and II:

https://www.physik.tu-dresden.de/~timm/personal/teaching/thmag_w09/lecturenotes.pdf
https://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/~jmjk/keeling/teaching/magnetism-notes.pdf

For section III on path integrals, the [Tong Lecture Notes on Statistical Field Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft/sft.pdf) are great.